# C# - LINQ - Group collection by date range

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq, group-by

Let's say I have the following collection of items:

```
ID: 1, Date: 10/01/2020 08:00
ID: 2, Date: 10/01/2020 12:00
ID: 3, Date: 10/01/2020 18:00
ID: 4, Date: 11/01/2020 06:00
ID: 5, Date: 11/01/2020 08:00

ID: 6, Date: 11/01/2020 08:01
ID: 7, Date: 11/01/2020 12:00
ID: 8, Date: 12/01/2020 01:00
ID: 9, Date: 12/01/2020 07:00

ID: 10, Date: 12/01/2020 12:00
ID: 11, Date: 12/01/2020 14:00
ID: 12, Date: 12/01/2020 16:00
```

Based on the above collection i want to create 3 groups, which contains records grouped by time interval - from an hour 08:00 till 07:59 next day:

XX.01.2020 08:00 - XX(+1).01.2020 07:59

The output grouped collection should look like this

```
**Group 1 (10.01.2020 08:00 - 11.01.2020 07:59):**
   ID: 1, Date: 10/01/2020 08:00
   ID: 2, Date: 10/01/2020 12:00
   ID: 3, Date: 10/01/2020 18:00
   ID: 4, Date: 11/01/2020 06:00
   ID: 5, Date: 11/01/2020 07:59
**Group 2 (11.01.2020 08:00 - 12.01.2020 07:59):**
   ID: 6, Date: 11/01/2020 08:00
   ID: 7, Date: 11/01/2020 12:00
   ID: 8, Date: 12/01/2020 01:00
   ID: 9, Date: 12/01/2020 07:00
**Group 3 (12.01.2020 08:00 - 13.01.2020 07:59):**
   ID: 10, Date: 12/01/2020 12:00
   ID: 11, Date: 12/01/2020 14:00
   ID: 12, Date: 12/01/2020 16:00
```

Is this possible using Linq?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what collection you have, but let's say you have `Dictionary<int, DateTime>`.

Then you could groupby like this, 'rounding' to the current day if it's after 8, or to the previous day if it is before 8:

```
    var groups = dictionary.GroupBy(x =>
        {
            var dt = x.Value;
            if (dt.Hour >= 8)
                return dt.Date;
            else
                return dt.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(24)).Date;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if you want this to run in database.

But I think one really easy way to go could be substracting 8 hours to make it a whole day, which you can use as the basis of grouping:

```csharp
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Date.AddHours(-8).Date);
```

And if you want to get a grouping with proper 'from' and 'to' dates, like how you seemed to specify, you can slap this projection to the end:

```csharp
    .Select(g => new {
        From = g.Key.AddHours(8),
        To = g.Key.AddHours(8).AddDays(1),
        Values = g.AsEnumerable()
    });
```

This might work for normal Linq on in-memory collections. Won't be translated to SQL though if you run it on `IQueryable` (unless I'm obtuse).

It's okay if you accept the other answer, if that looks better to you. :)